# What are the connotations of Mark 6:21 mentioning 'the opportune time'?

Tags: mark

We have in Mark 6, a flashback of the martyrdom of John the Baptist at the hands of Herod. John was detained for speaking against the unholy alliance of Herod who had taken his brother's wife as his own. In verse 21, we see Mark mentioning: "And finally the opportune time came". Mark then proceeds to narrate the dance of Herodya's daughter in front of Herod and his guests, his granting of a wish to the girl and her asking, after consulting her mother, for the life of John. We see Herod regretting, but obliging the girl. The narrative unfolds in the form of a totally unplanned event. But then, why does Mark mention the 'final coming of the opportune time'? What do Bible scholars tell us about the connotations of Mark 6:21?

Mark 6:21 NIV

> Finally the opportune time came. On his birthday Herod gave a banquet for his high officials and military commanders and the leading men of Galilee.

Comment: So Herodias **nursed a grudge** against John and **wanted to kill him**. But she was not able to, *because Herod feared John and protected him*, knowing him to be a righteous and holy man.

Finally the opportune time came.

**She went out and said to her mother, “What shall I ask for?”**

“The head of John the Baptist,” she answered.him.

Mark 6:19-20,21,24

Comment: Thanks, davidianwalker. Please also state what you conclude from those verses .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the previous two verses:

> Mark 6:19, 20 - So Herodias held a grudge against John and wanted to
> kill him. But she had been unable, because Herod feared John and
> protected him, knowing that he was a righteous and holy man. When he
> heard John’s words, he was greatly perplexed; yet he listened to him
> gladly.

Thus, the angry wife of Herod was looking for an opportunity to remove John and his moral truth-telling.

The operative words in V21 on V21 are:

- εὔκαιρος (eukairos) = literally "good time", more idiomatically, opportune, or suitable, or appropriate time.
- ἡμέρα (hemera) = "day"

Thus, the first part of V21 would read (overly literally):

> And having come [a] day opportune, when Herod on his birthday ...

Thus, Herodias saw a lucky confluence of events that created the opportunity, ie, the opportune time to extract revenge on John for his infuriating moral truth-telling.

Gill comments as follows:

> **And when a convenient day was come,....** For Herodias; who had long sought and watched for an opportunity of avenging herself on John, and
> such a time Herod's birthday proved; ... his own birthday, which he
> kept as a festival, in eating, and drinking, and dancing; and so was a
> very opportune and seasonable time for Herodias to take the advantage
> of Herod when in a good humour, amidst his company, and in his cups,
> to solicit that, which she had often done without success: and so it
> was now,